# Bing Maps Ajax v7 Pushpin Moving on Zoom/Pan

Tags: javascript, ajax, bing-maps

I'm using bing maps ajax v7.  On map zoom/pan the pushpins seem to be animating/rendering needlessly.  They are not anchored statically to their coordinates as they should be or previously were (before zoom/pan) and on zoom/pan they seem to be animating/rendering from a different position off screen.

This happens in all browsers (Mac: [Chrome, FF, Safari], Windows: [IE, Chrome, FF]).

Seems to be similar to this SO Q: [Virtual Earth (Bing) Pin "moves" when zoom level changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671387/virtual-earth-bing-pin-moves-when-zoom-level-changes) - but different api version and the scale solution isn't applicable.

Anyone run into this?

Comment: First, did you set the anchor of the pushpin while using Bing Maps AJAX v7 control? See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427629.aspx
Secondly, it might be interesting to share a part of code that will help us to reproduce the problem you're facing or even on jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was running into this exact issue. When I would zoom out or pan, the pushpins would animate every time, making for a terrible user experience. I found out that I had some global styles being applied to my site to make links animate into position when I scaled the browser. This may come default in some style sheet boilerplate. This was the offending style

```
  a {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    /* For Chrome <= 25, Safari <= 6.0, iOS Safari <= 6.1, Android Browser <= 4.3 */
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    /* For Firefox <= 15 */
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    /* For Opera <= 12 */
    transition: all 0.5s ease; }
```

I targeted the map pushpins directly by applying the following style:

```
/* Prevent a tag inside of map to animate */
.MapPushpinBase {
    -webkit-transition: none;
    -moz-transition: none;
    -o-transition: none;
    transition: none;}
```

which effectively removes the CSS animations on the pushpins.

Problem solved (for me)